# Ubuntu 20.04 Hangs when Unlocking

Tags: 20.04, dell, systemd, lock-screen, gdm

The problem manifests as follows:
I walk away from my computer, come back about 15 minutes later to find that the screen has gone black and the computer has locked (as expected). I tap the space bar to wake it, which works, presenting me with the lock screen, where I enter my password. Then the icon spins for about half a turn then stops. I can then wait indefinitely and the lock screen never progresses. The mouse cursor still works but nothing else responds. I can recover without rebooting by switching to another tty and restarting the gdm service, though this (as expected) closes all open programs.

I tried to log in around 12:19, so it might have something to do with the "systemd-logind: got pause" logs. The other suspicious thing is the "Power button: device removed", though I'm not sure thats unexpected. I've attached my syslog, hwifno, and nvidia-smi output.

So far I've tried using the Nouveau drivers, using the 470 and 510 version of Nvidia proprietary drivers, and disabling all Gnome shell extensions. I also tried disabling swap and hibernation in case it was due to failed hibernation, I also disabled secure boot from a tip on another forum. I'm using no dispaly scaling on Xorg with two 4k monitors over displayport.

Another thing of note is that this is a Dell pre-built Precision 5820 that came pre-installed with Ubuntu, so it has some of Dell's "Matira" and "Somerville" packages that I can't find much about.

Let me know if I missed any important info.

syslog:
https://gist.github.com/ShaneEverittM/a9a1eac9b7b28486388219166542929e

hwinfo --short:

```
cpu:
                       Intel(R) Xeon(R) W-2255 CPU @ 3.70GHz, 1200 MHz
                       Intel(R) Xeon(R) W-2255 CPU @ 3.70GHz, 3700 MHz
                       Intel(R) Xeon(R) W-2255 CPU @ 3.70GHz, 3700 MHz
                       Intel(R) Xeon(R) W-2255 CPU @ 3.70GHz, 3700 MHz
                       Intel(R) Xeon(R) W-2255 CPU @ 3.70GHz, 3700 MHz
                       Intel(R) Xeon(R) W-2255 CPU @ 3.70GHz, 3700 MHz
                       Intel(R) Xeon(R) W-2255 CPU @ 3.70GHz, 3700 MHz
                       Intel(R) Xeon(R) W-2255 CPU @ 3.70GHz, 3700 MHz
                       Intel(R) Xeon(R) W-2255 CPU @ 3.70GHz, 3700 MHz
                       Intel(R) Xeon(R) W-2255 CPU @ 3.70GHz, 3700 MHz
                       Intel(R) Xeon(R) W-2255 CPU @ 3.70GHz, 3700 MHz
                       Intel(R) Xeon(R) W-2255 CPU @ 3.70GHz, 3700 MHz
                       Intel(R) Xeon(R) W-2255 CPU @ 3.70GHz, 3700 MHz
                       Intel(R) Xeon(R) W-2255 CPU @ 3.70GHz, 3700 MHz
                       Intel(R) Xeon(R) W-2255 CPU @ 3.70GHz, 3700 MHz
                       Intel(R) Xeon(R) W-2255 CPU @ 3.70GHz, 3700 MHz
                       Intel(R) Xeon(R) W-2255 CPU @ 3.70GHz, 3700 MHz
                       Intel(R) Xeon(R) W-2255 CPU @ 3.70GHz, 3700 MHz
                       Intel(R) Xeon(R) W-2255 CPU @ 3.70GHz, 3700 MHz
                       Intel(R) Xeon(R) W-2255 CPU @ 3.70GHz, 3700 MHz
keyboard:
  /dev/input/event3    ZSA ErgoDox EZ
  /dev/input/event2    AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
  /dev/input/event20   MX Master Keyboard
mouse:
  /dev/input/mice      ZSA ErgoDox EZ
  /dev/input/mice      MX Master Mouse
graphics card:
                       nVidia VGA compatible controller
sound:
                       nVidia Audio device
                       Intel 200 Series PCH HD Audio
storage:
                       Intel C600/X79 series chipset SATA RAID Controller
                       SK hynix Non-Volatile memory controller
                       Intel RAID bus controller
network:
  wls1                 Intel Wireless 8265 / 8275
  eno1                 Intel Ethernet Connection (5) I219-LM
network interface:
  wls1                 Ethernet network interface
  lo                   Loopback network interface
  docker0              Ethernet network interface
  eno1                 Ethernet network interface
  br-59c1c1f0589d      Ethernet network interface
  mpqemubr0            Ethernet network interface
disk:
  /dev/nvme0n1         SK hynix Disk
  /dev/sda             Generic SD/MMC CRW
partition:
  /dev/nvme0n1p1       Partition
  /dev/nvme0n1p2       Partition
  /dev/nvme0n1p3       Partition
usb controller:
                       Intel JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016]
                       Intel 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
bios:
                       BIOS
bridge:
                       Intel 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #1
                       Intel JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016]
                       Intel C422 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller
                       Texas Instruments XIO2001 PCI Express-to-PCI Bridge
                       Intel JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016]
                       Intel Sky Lake-E DMI3 Registers
                       Intel JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016]
                       Intel Sky Lake-E PCI Express Root Port D
                       Intel JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016]
                       Intel 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #9
                       Intel 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #7
                       Intel Sky Lake-E PCI Express Root Port A
                       Intel JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016]
                       Intel Sky Lake-E PCI Express Root Port C
                       Intel Sky Lake-E PCI Express Root Port A
hub:
                       Realtek 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub
                       Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
                       Realtek 4-Port USB 3.0 Hub
                       Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
                       Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
                       Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
memory:
                       Main Memory
bluetooth:
                       Intel Bluetooth Device
unknown:
                       FPU
                       DMA controller
                       PIC
                       Keyboard controller
                       Intel Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E LM Channel 2
                       Intel 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family Power Management Controller
                       Intel Sky Lake-E PCU Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E LMDP Channel 1
                       Intel Sky Lake-E Ubox Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E IOxAPIC Configuration Registers
                       Intel Performance counters
                       Intel Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E CBDMA Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E LMS Channel 2
                       Intel Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E IOxAPIC Configuration Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E PCU Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E LM Channel 1
                       Intel Sky Lake-E RAS Configuration Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E CBDMA Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E DECS Channel 2
                       Intel Sky Lake-E LMS Channel 1
                       Intel Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E RAS Configuration Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E PCU Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E Integrated Memory Controller
                       Intel Sky Lake-E VT-d
                       Intel Sky Lake-E Integrated Memory Controller
                       Intel Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E CBDMA Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E M3KTI Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E IOxAPIC Configuration Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E Integrated Memory Controller
                       Intel Sky Lake-E M2PCI Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E VT-d
                       Intel 200 Series PCH CSME HECI #1
                       Intel Sky Lake-E Integrated Memory Controller
                       Intel Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
                       Intel Performance counters
                       Intel Sky Lake-E RAS Configuration Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E Integrated Memory Controller
                       Intel Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E M2PCI Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E CBDMA Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E VT-d
                       Intel Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E LMS Channel 2
                       Intel Sky Lake-E Integrated Memory Controller
                       Intel Sky Lake-E PCU Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E Ubox Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E CBDMA Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E LMDP Channel 2
                       Intel JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 NHI (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016]
                       Intel Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E Integrated Memory Controller
                       Intel Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E DECS Channel 2
                       Intel Sky Lake-E PCU Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E LMS Channel 1
                       Intel Sky Lake-E M2PCI Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E CBDMA Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E LM Channel 2
                       Intel Sky Lake-E LMDP Channel 1
                       Intel Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E PCU Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E Integrated Memory Controller
                       Intel Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E CBDMA Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E M3KTI Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E LM Channel 1
                       Intel Performance counters
                       Intel Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E IOAPIC
                       Intel Sky Lake-E PCU Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E Integrated Memory Controller
                       Intel Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E M3KTI Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
                       Intel 200 Series PCH Thermal Subsystem
                       Intel Sky Lake-E Integrated Memory Controller
                       Intel Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
                       Intel Performance counters
                       Intel Sky Lake-E RAS
                       Intel Sky Lake-E Integrated Memory Controller
                       Intel Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E M2PCI Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E LMDP Channel 2
                       Intel Sky Lake-E Integrated Memory Controller
                       Intel 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family SMBus Controller
                       Intel Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E Ubox Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E MM/Vt-d Configuration Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E CBDMA Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
                       Intel Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
                       Serial controller
                       ZSA ErgoDox EZ
  /dev/ttyUSB0         Cygnal Integrated CP2102/CP2109 UART Bridge Controller [CP210x family]
                       Future Technology Devices International FT232H Single HS USB-UART/FIFO IC
  /dev/ttyUSB1         Cygnal Integrated CP210x UART Bridge
```

nvidia-smi:

```
Mon Feb 28 12:56:56 2022       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 510.47.03    Driver Version: 510.47.03    CUDA Version: 11.6     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA T600         Off  | 00000000:91:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 38%   42C    P5    N/A /  41W |   1798MiB /  4096MiB |      5%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A    264874      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                213MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A    265114      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                979MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A    265472      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell               93MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A    266020      G   ...AAAAAAAAA= --shared-files       74MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A    267981      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox          372MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A    268392      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            1MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A    268447      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            1MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A    271041      G   .../debug.log --shared-files       50MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try reinstall lightdm and reboot

```
sudo apt autoremove lightdm --purge
sudo apt install lightdm
sudo reboot
```

If this doesn't, reinstall gdm3 as well

```
sudo apt autoremove gdm3 --purge
sudo apt install gdm3
sudo reboot
```

Comment: What are the odds you think this works, given all the things I've tried? It just seems like an operation that is somewhat risky and I don't want to brick my work computer.

Comment: I just offer how I fixed such similar issues. It's update to you to try it or not. Estentially the operation reinstall gdm3 with cleanup previous gdm3 data.